# InfluxDB import csv file

Tags: influxdb

I run influx DB locally from localhost:8086 address. I created a bucket, TestDB. I add data for it, by uploading a csv file from my hdd. After I drop the csv file, I get this:

[image]

When I click on see uploaded data, I'm redirected to Data Explorer. I see my bucket but without any measurement (table) in it.

[image]

How could I get my csv's values in TestDB's measurement?